# How to handle the event for the UICollectionView custom cell?

Tags: ios

I have created a custom cell for the UICollectionView. The custom cell has two UIImageView - imageView1 and imageView2.

How should I handle the event for each imageView? I can get handle only the cell event on didSelectedItemIndex delegate of UICollectionView. I want to get handle for each imageView.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    PhotosViewCell *cell = (PhotosViewCell*)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

 int tag1 = cell.imageView1.tag;
 int tag2 = cell.imageview2.tag;

 ....
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "event"? Do you want to be able to react on tapping on these images?

Comment: Yes, I want to get the tap event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your cellForRowAtIndexPath method define tap gesture recognizer with selector and assign it to your image.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(productImageTap:)];
[cell.imageView1 addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
[cell.imageView1 setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[cell.imageView2 addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
[cell.imageView2 setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

Then you can do anything you want in productImageTap method. Just get indexPath via locationInView method..

```
- (void)productImageTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    CGPoint point = [gesture locationInView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:point];
    PhotosViewCell *cell = (PhotosViewCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    //do whatever you want with cell properties.. 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
Actually I was trying to use UITapGestureRecognizer. But I missed to use setUserIneratctionEnable method. 
I added it and the event I wanted, works well now.
Thanks again!